# How do you clear your Visual Studio Code cache on a Mac/Linux Machine?

Tags: linux, macos, visual-studio-code

How do I flush the cache for my Visual Studio Code on my Mac El Capitan OS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clear file content cache in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45216264/clear-file-content-cache-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Yes. I believe Prancer's answer below includes the same solution found in that link plus more. Thank you for the link @Da2da2

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I believe this is what you are asking... how to **clear your file history cache** (pulled from this [git issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3260)). It is very simple!

To clear your entire history ->
[image]

To clear history of specific files -> **">Remove From History"**

If you are looking to **clear your user or workspace settings**, they are just files that can be cleared inside VSCode or manually deleted from your file system. This is documented in the [VSCode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations).

Comment: This solution is not only for macOS but also helped me out on Manjaro Linux. I gutess it works on Windows as well. Just wanted to make sure, People don't get scared by "macOS" and go on searching ;)

Answer (score 65):

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/Cache/*
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/CachedData/*
```

Answer (score 18):

In my case, vscode always opened several projects at launch.
To fix this bug I had to clear ["workspace memory"](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/42948)  (the local storage folder)

On mac OS

```sh
rm -rf ~/Library/Application Support/Code/Local Storage
```

### Local Storage location

- Windows: `C:\Users\<userid>\AppData\Roaming\Code\Local Storage`
- Linux: `/home/<userid>/.config/Code/Local Storage`
- macOS: `/Users/<userid>/Library/Application Support/Code/Local Storage`