# Clear file content cache in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

My Visual Studio code, on a Windows machine, keeps on showing me the previous content of a file even after this one has been updated, while `notepad ++` doesn't behave in the same way.

Is there a way to somehow clean the cache so as to receive fresh content every time?

Comment: Have you tried pressing ctrl + r ?

Comment: See also about Visual Studio Code cache: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66295480/470749

Comment: Note: in my experience, this also can result in a large speedup if you haven't cleared your cache for a while.

Answer (score 262, accepted):

I think, I understood correct. You can follow below steps.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. type command **Clear Editor History**
3. Press Enter

It will solve your problem.

Comment: Works great for clearing deleted files/moved files from Quick Open.

Comment: I keep seeing a Loading at my definition.

Comment: Perfect for seeing only the newer names of the same files instead of duplicates.  Thanks!

Comment: This also helped me during powershell development, having debugger quirks...

Comment: Where do I do this? doing it in the browser brings up the printer. Doing it on the desktop or in Visual Studio does nothing

Comment: @NickyLarson The question is about VS code. Not Visual Studio

Comment: will this going to delete every saved workplaces?

Comment: It doesn't afford much. Using the disk analyzer reveals the huge amount of memory still in the cache folder because of vscode.

Answer (score 12):

For me on **macOS** the following has worked:

1. Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Type command **Clear Search History**
3. Press Enter

Then for the search results:

1. Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Type command **Clear Search Results**
3. Press Enter

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me.

Adding this task in `.vscode/tasks.json`:

```json
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "clear-editor-history",
      "command": "${command:workbench.action.clearEditorHistory}"
    }
  ]
}
```

And using the task in launch configuration (`.vscode/launch`)

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      ...
      "preLaunchTask": "clear-editor-history"
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 go to search box and enter "%appdata%". After, delete the folder "code"

Comment: This deletes quite a bit more than just old files.

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows 10**

1. Go to C:\Users<Username>
2. **Delete .vscode Folder.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).