# Visual Studio Code keeps opening the release notes

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.15.1, as of this writing.  When Code did the last update, it began auto-opening a release notes file for that version.  But now, *Every time* that I open Visual studio, from task bar, opening an associated file, or anywhere else, that same release notes file keeps opening *after* the file I tried to open.  Which means I have to close it to get to what I was wanting to work on.  This is clearly extremely frustrating, as I can't even find where the release notes are kept as a file to move/rename them!

Searching on the web has been next to useless, as it just keeps showing links to websites about releases of Visual Studio code.  I can't get the search engine to understand I want to talk about a *file* that *contains* release notes.  Any ideas?  Maybe I missed a setting, but I've been digging and I've yet to actually find something related in the editor settings.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Please file an issue and we'll take a look: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new

Answer (score 57):

[image: Gear Button]
Click **Manage** (gear) icons on your bottom left side, choose **Settings** and then type *release notes* on the searchbar (Search settings). Uncheck the "**Show Release Notes after an update**"

Comment: Click into _Settings_ to get to the searchbar now.

Answer (score 5):

In Windows (probably works on Mac too) I did this:

Press Ctrl + Shift + P

type command: Clear Editor History

Press Enter

[stolen from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45216264/clear-file-content-cache-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you're still having issues but I had the same problem with VS code 1.19.1 release notes.

I created a [Github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/41108) and they were able to resolve it by suggesting to delete the `Local Cache` folder.

Not sure what OS you're on but for macOS it was in `/Users/<your user>/Library/Application Support/Code/Local Storage`.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a checkbox in the Release Notes themselves which is the equivalent of the setting `Update: Show Release Notes` - the setting can be toggled either from the Setting itself or an open Release Notes.  From [v1.75 Release Notes: Opt out of showing](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_75.md#easier-opt-out-of-release-notes-after-update)  Currently in the Insiders Build v1.75:

[image: enable show release notes]

Answer (score 0):

If you would rather use your keyboard instead of mousing, add this to your [`settings.json`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65909052)

```json
"update.showReleaseNotes": false,
```

On my Mac the path is:

`~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`

Plus…

> You can now opt out of reading the release notes after every update, directly from the release notes editor.

Details in [Easier opt-out of release notes after update](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_75#_easier-optout-of-release-notes-after-update) from January 2023 v1.75 release notes.