# How to disable all the "what's new" screens on VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Almost every time I open a file in VS Code, I have my focus stolen by a new tab with a what's new content, either from an update of VS Code itself (it's very actively developed) or one of the extensions.

Is there a way those can be disabled?

Comment: disable automatic update of extensions and VSC itself

Comment: Please add the exact quotes of the alert message to this question for future searchers.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74804854/836330 for another way to toggle off showing the vscode Release Notes after each update (only applies to vscode itself, not extensions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can set **update.showReleaseNote** to false or you can uncheck **Update: Show Release Notes** in your Settings.

Comment: Changing this setting will disable the Release Notes screen only for VSCode, it will not prevent installed extensions from showing their own Release Notes pages when they update.

Answer (score 1):

VSCode 1.75 (Jan. 2023) does offer an [Easier opt-out of release notes after update](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_75.md#easier-opt-out-of-release-notes-after-update):

> You can now opt out of reading the release notes after every update, directly from the release notes editor.
> This will reflect and update the `update.showReleaseNotes` setting.
>
> [image]

Comment: See my comment above from two weeks ago on the same.  Didn't want to post the same answer twice (mods have taken exception to that before) so I commented with the link.