# Settings.json keeps opening in Visual Studio Vode

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide

I have this weird issue in Visual Studio Code (v1.67.0 (Universal) on Mac) where the editor keeps opening `Settings.json`

It says something has changed in the file, however I can't figure out what it is. After saving again and closing the file reopens itself after a while and says it has been modified.

When comparing, no changes in the file are visible. I tried deleting the cache as mention in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45913900/visual-studio-code-keeps-opening-the-release-notes) Stack Overflow topic however that didn't make a difference.

Anyone else experiencing the same issue?

Cheers,
Allard