# VS for Mac has stopped being able to debug native projects in a Xamarin app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I have developed a Xamarin Forms app that is composed of a shared base project (using netstandard 2.0), that contains most of the code, and Android & iOS project that contains specific features for each platform.

I don't know how or when it happened (as most of the development is done in the base project), but suddenly I can't debug any code that is within the Android or iOS projects (I can debug the code in the shared project just fine), and I get a "Source Not Available" message when I try to step into any code that runs on them (breakpoints don't work either).

Obviously everything is compiled in debug mode, and I've checked that "Debug Information: Full" is set for both of them. As an example, this is the Android Build Configuration of the Android project:

[image: Android Build Configuration]

Any hints on what could cause this behavior would be appreciated.

Comment: You can firstly delete the folder `bin` and  `obj` in share project and specific platforms . Then clean and rebuild it. And make sure the version of VS for Mac is up to date .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I just deleted the bin and obj folders for all projects, and no luck. The version of VS is 8.3.10 (build 2) and there are no further updates available.

Comment: Just remove the reference of your shared project to platform specific and add back. That might help.

Comment: I was having issues with this on the most recent version of xcode + visual studio for mac. I had to switch to the preview channel for debugging to work again

Comment: @salgiza Have you tried remove cache of Visual Studio for Mac? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46246437/visual-studio-for-mac-cache-location

Comment: @NirmalSubedi It is the other way around. It's the platform specific projects that reference the shared project. Or, to put it in a different perspective: I'm actually running/debugging the Android project, but I can't debug its code, only the code of the shared project that it references!

Comment: @JanNepraš I just deleted all cache folders, but no luck :(

Comment: @salgiza Then let's try Visual Studio for Mac preview. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/update?view=vsmac-2019