# Visual Studio Code reopens too many unsaved tabs upon startup

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a problem with VSCode: when I open the program, it always opens like 6000 tabs.

I wanted to replace a string in the files, and it searched through all files. As it turns out, these were around 6000 files. When I use the command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K W</kbd> it will ask me to save, don't save, or cancel.

I am trying to get this solved, first tried to close all others but still same dialog. I uninstalled VS Code in the hope that it would stop opening these files, no luck.

Furthermore, I searched regedit to find any information about the program, there is a lot, but I cannot find the file that is responsible for opening all these files.

The files don't exist anymore except in some memory of VS Code.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: if you delete the sqlite3 db (and the backup) belonging to the workspace all tabs are gone, search the correct folder in `.....\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage`

Comment: can't you use `File > Save All` and command `View: Close All Editors`

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71176892/how-can-i-properly-clear-the-backup-file-cache-of-vscode)

I delete some folders inside '\AppData\Roaming\Code\Backups'.

Now VS Code runs normal again.

Comment: I had a similar problem and deleting the backups worked for me as well. On Macs, the backups folder is in `$HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Code/Backups`. I think the problem might be caused by a sudden/forced shut down. Some documentation here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_hot-exit

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set

> "window.restoreWindows": "none"

in the settings and restart vscode?